# Updated Wordpress - Media Library Blank - MediaElementPlayer is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I updatet a wordpress multisite installation to the newest version 4.9. After the update, the media gallery in the backend is not showing any images. Its blank. The images are still in the uploads folder and i deactivated all plugins.

When i open the media gallery i get the following errors inside the console:

```
ReferenceError: MediaElementPlayer is not defined
TypeError: $(...).not(...).filter(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function
```

Comment: Same here! Just updated to 4.9 and now cannot add any media to my posts.

Answer (score 7):

It's a new known bug, [see here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42574). They are working on a solution.

For the moment I have changed language in WordPress settings from `de-DE-formal` ("Deutsch (Sie)") to `de-DE` ("Deutsch").

Comment: Thanks. Had the same problem. Changing to "de-DE" helped. What a stupid bug.

Comment: Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which language have you activated?
I had the same problem, but in my case there where also the error:

> TypeError: Language code must have format 2-3 letters and. optionally,
>   hyphen, underscore followed by 2 more letters

In my case, the language "de_DE_formal" (Deutsch (Sie)) was activated.
After I set the language to the "de_DE" (Deutsch) the error was gone.